# Need to find date's between 2 date's in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need help with query to find all the dates that between 31/12/2009 and 31/02/2010

In SQL Server 2008

i try this:

```
SELECT  convert(varchar(50), MyDate, 103)
where convert(varchar(50), MyDate, 103) >= '31/12/2009' and convert(varchar(50), MyDate, 103) <='31/02/2010'
```

but it give me wrong result

why ?

Comment: You should clarify your question with an example of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had a different interpretation of the question:  "how to generate all the dates between a certain range?"

Here's a solution to that:

```
--define start and end limits
Declare @todate datetime, @fromdate datetime
Select @fromdate='2009-03-01', @todate='2009-04-10' 

;With DateSequence( Date ) as
(
    Select @fromdate as Date
        union all
    Select dateadd(day, 1, Date)
        from DateSequence
        where Date < @todate
)

--select result
Select * from DateSequence option (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

There is a nice [article](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/t-sql-using-common-table-expressions-cte-to-generate-sequences/) that shows how to generate sequences (numbers, dates, times) using CTEs.

---

**Edit:**

After clarification, the issue seems to be the date format being input: dd/mm/yyyy.

SQL Server expects the format mm/dd/yyyy.

I would simply transform it before running the select statement:

```
-- Assuming two variables, @inputFromDate and @inputToDate, in the format of dd/mm/yyyy...

declare @fromDate varchar(10), @toDate varchar(10)
set @fromDate = 
substring(@inputFromDate, 3, 2) + '/' + 
substring(@inputFromDate, 1, 2) + '/' + 
substring(@inputFromDate, 7, 4)

set @toDate = 
substring(@inputToDate, 3, 2) + '/' + 
substring(@inputToDate, 1, 2) + '/' + 
substring(@inputToDate, 7, 4)

select * from SomeTable where dateCol >= @fromDate and dateCol < @toDate
-- you can change the < or >= comparisons according to your needs
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought the OP meant too.

Comment: thank's for the help, i need something simple select...#03/03/2010..between...  and i need this kind of date format (dd/mm/yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

If the `MyDate` column is a `datetime`, as it appears to be, then it's already in the right "format".  **Don't** convert it to a `varchar(50)` in the predicate condition - this makes your query non-sargable and will kill performance on any indexes you might have.

Instead, take your parameters as `date` or `datetime` instances:

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDate >= @BeginDate
AND MyDate <= @EndDate
```

Your query should not depend on a specific date format in the input parameters - those parameters are not `varchar` types, they are `datetime` (or `date`).  When you run this query or stored procedure from whatever environment the application is in and supply binding parameters (you **are** using bind parameters, right?), said library will automatically handle any formatting issues.

If you try to use the `>=` and `<=` operators on character representations of dates, with any format other than the ISO standard `yyyymmdd`, you will get the wrong results, because the alphabetical order is different from the temporal order.  Don't do this.

If you simply need to write an ad-hoc query, i.e. this isn't being run from any programming environment, then simply do not use the `dd/mm/yyyy` format.  Use the ISO date format instead; it is unambiguous and implicitly convertible to `datetime` values:

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDate >= '20091231'
AND MyDate <= '20100231'
```

Honestly, no other solution is acceptable in my mind.  For ad-hoc queries, always use the unambiguous ISO standard for dates.  For applications connecting to the database, always use bind parameters.  If you're doing anything else, you're writing code that's either unreliable, insecure, or both.

Answer (score 0):

[BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) is always a good reference...

Start with [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
DECLARE @FROMDATE DATETIME 
DECLARE @TODATE DATETIME 
SET @FROMDATE = GETDATE()
SET @TODATE = GETDATE()+7 
;WITH DATEINFO(DATES) AS (SELECT @FROMDATE UNION ALL SELECT DATES + 1 FROM DATEINFO WHERE DATES < @TODATE) 
SELECT * FROM DATEINFO OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```